# Decoding and playing audio with ffmpeg and XAudio2 - frequency raito wrong

Tags: c++, windows, audio, ffmpeg, xaudio2

I'm using ffmpeg to decode audio and output it using the XAudio2 API, it works and plays synced with the video output using the pts. But it's high pitched (i.e. sounds like chipmunks).

Setting breakpoints I can see it has sets the correct sample rate from the audio codec in CreateSourceVoice. I'm stumped.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include "DVDAudioDevice.h"

HANDLE m_hBufferEndEvent;

CDVDAudio::CDVDAudio()
{
    m_pXAudio2 = NULL;
    m_pMasteringVoice = NULL;
    m_pSourceVoice = NULL;
    m_pWfx  = NULL;

    m_VoiceCallback = NULL;

    m_hBufferEndEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, false, false, "Buffer end event");
}

CDVDAudio::~CDVDAudio()
{
    m_pXAudio2 = NULL;
    m_pMasteringVoice = NULL;
    m_pSourceVoice = NULL;
    m_pWfx  = NULL;

    m_VoiceCallback = NULL;

    CloseHandle(m_hBufferEndEvent);
    m_hBufferEndEvent = NULL;
}

bool CDVDAudio::Create(int iChannels, int iBitrate, int iBitsPerSample, bool bPasstrough)
{
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    HRESULT hr = XAudio2Create( &m_pXAudio2, 0, XAUDIO2_DEFAULT_PROCESSOR);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_pXAudio2->CreateMasteringVoice( &m_pMasteringVoice );
    }

    // Create source voice
    WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE wfx;
    memset(&wfx, 0, sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE));

    wfx.Format.wFormatTag           = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    wfx.Format.nSamplesPerSec       = iBitrate;//pFFMpegData->pAudioCodecCtx->sample_rate;//48000 by default
    wfx.Format.nChannels            = iChannels;//pFFMpegData->pAudioCodecCtx->channels;
    wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample       = 16;
    wfx.Format.nBlockAlign          = wfx.Format.nChannels*16/8;
    wfx.Format.nAvgBytesPerSec      = wfx.Format.nSamplesPerSec * wfx.Format.nBlockAlign;
    wfx.Format.cbSize               = sizeof(WAVEFORMATEXTENSIBLE)-sizeof(WAVEFORMATEX);
    wfx.Samples.wValidBitsPerSample = wfx.Format.wBitsPerSample;

    if(wfx.Format.nChannels == 1)
    {
        wfx.dwChannelMask = SPEAKER_MONO;
    }
    else if(wfx.Format.nChannels == 2)
    {
        wfx.dwChannelMask = SPEAKER_STEREO;
    }
    else if(wfx.Format.nChannels == 5)
    {
        wfx.dwChannelMask = SPEAKER_5POINT1;
    }

    wfx.SubFormat = KSDATAFORMAT_SUBTYPE_PCM;

    unsigned int flags = 0;//XAUDIO2_VOICE_NOSRC;// | XAUDIO2_VOICE_NOPITCH;

    //Source voice

    m_VoiceCallback = new StreamingVoiceCallback(this);

    hr = m_pXAudio2->CreateSourceVoice(&m_pSourceVoice,(WAVEFORMATEX*)&wfx, 0 , 1.0f, m_VoiceCallback);

    if(!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return false;

    // Start sound
    hr = m_pSourceVoice->Start(0);

    if(!SUCCEEDED(hr))
        return false;

    return true;
}

DWORD CDVDAudio::AddPackets(unsigned char* data, DWORD len)
{  
        memset(&m_SoundBuffer,0,sizeof(XAUDIO2_BUFFER));

        m_SoundBuffer.AudioBytes = len;
        m_SoundBuffer.pAudioData = data;
        m_SoundBuffer.pContext = NULL;//(VOID*)data;

        XAUDIO2_VOICE_STATE state;

        while(m_pSourceVoice->GetState( &state ), state.BuffersQueued > 60)
        {
            WaitForSingleObject( m_hBufferEndEvent, INFINITE );
        }

        m_pSourceVoice->SubmitSourceBuffer( &m_SoundBuffer );

    return 0;
}

void CDVDAudio::Destroy()
{
    m_pMasteringVoice->DestroyVoice();
    m_pXAudio2->Release();

    m_pSourceVoice->DestroyVoice();

    delete m_VoiceCallback;
    m_VoiceCallback = NULL;
}
```

```
#include "DVDAudioCodecFFmpeg.h"
#include "Log.h"

CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg() : CDVDAudioCodec()
{
    m_iBufferSize = 0;
    m_pCodecContext = NULL;
    m_bOpenedCodec = false;
}

CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::~CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg()
{
    Dispose();
}

bool CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Open(AVCodecID codecID, int iChannels, int iSampleRate)
{
    AVCodec* pCodec;
    m_bOpenedCodec = false;

    av_register_all();

    pCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(codecID);

    m_pCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(pCodec);//avcodec_alloc_context();
    avcodec_get_context_defaults3(m_pCodecContext, pCodec);

    if (!pCodec)
    {
        CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Open() Unable to find codec");
        return false;
    }

    m_pCodecContext->debug_mv = 0;
    m_pCodecContext->debug = 0;
    m_pCodecContext->workaround_bugs = 1;

    if (pCodec->capabilities & CODEC_CAP_TRUNCATED)
        m_pCodecContext->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_TRUNCATED;

    m_pCodecContext->channels = iChannels;
    m_pCodecContext->sample_rate = iSampleRate;
    //m_pCodecContext->bits_per_sample = 24;

/* //FIXME BRENT
  if( ExtraData && ExtraSize > 0 )
  {
    m_pCodecContext->extradata_size = ExtraSize;
    m_pCodecContext->extradata = m_dllAvCodec.av_mallocz(ExtraSize + FF_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE);
    memcpy(m_pCodecContext->extradata, ExtraData, ExtraSize);
  }
*/
    // set acceleration
    //m_pCodecContext->dsp_mask = FF_MM_FORCE | FF_MM_MMX | FF_MM_MMXEXT | FF_MM_SSE; //BRENT

    if (avcodec_open2(m_pCodecContext, pCodec, NULL) < 0)
    {
        CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Open() Unable to open codec");
        Dispose();
        return false;
    }

    m_bOpenedCodec = true;
    return true;
}

void CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Dispose()
{
    if (m_pCodecContext)
    {
        if (m_bOpenedCodec) avcodec_close(m_pCodecContext);
        m_bOpenedCodec = false;
        av_free(m_pCodecContext);
        m_pCodecContext = NULL;
    }
    m_iBufferSize = 0;
}

int CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Decode(BYTE* pData, int iSize)
{
    int iBytesUsed;
    if (!m_pCodecContext) return -1;

    //Copy into a FFMpeg AVPAcket again
    AVPacket packet;
    av_init_packet(&packet);

    packet.data=pData;
    packet.size=iSize;

    int iOutputSize = AVCODEC_MAX_AUDIO_FRAME_SIZE; //BRENT

    iBytesUsed = avcodec_decode_audio3(m_pCodecContext, (int16_t *)m_buffer, &iOutputSize/*m_iBufferSize*/, &packet);

    m_iBufferSize = iOutputSize;//BRENT

    return iBytesUsed;
}

int CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::GetData(BYTE** dst)
{
    *dst = m_buffer;
    return m_iBufferSize;
}

void CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::Reset()
{
    if (m_pCodecContext) avcodec_flush_buffers(m_pCodecContext);
}

int CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::GetChannels()
{
    if (m_pCodecContext) return m_pCodecContext->channels;
    return 0;
}

int CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::GetSampleRate()
{
    if (m_pCodecContext) return m_pCodecContext->sample_rate;
    return 0;
}

int CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg::GetBitsPerSample()
{
    if (m_pCodecContext) return 16;
    return 0;
}
```

`#include "DVDPlayerAudio.h"
#include "DVDDemuxUtils.h"
#include "Log.h"

#include <assert.h>
#include "DVDAudioCodecFFmpeg.h" //FIXME Move to a codec factory!!

CDVDPlayerAudio::CDVDPlayerAudio(CDVDClock* pClock) : CThread()
{
    m_pClock = pClock;
    m_pAudioCodec = NULL;
    m_bInitializedOutputDevice = false;
    m_iSourceChannels = 0;
    m_audioClock = 0;

//  m_currentPTSItem.pts = DVD_NOPTS_VALUE;
//  m_currentPTSItem.timestamp = 0;

    SetSpeed(DVD_PLAYSPEED_NORMAL);

    InitializeCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection);
    m_messageQueue.SetMaxDataSize(10 * 16 * 1024);
//  g_dvdPerformanceCounter.EnableAudioQueue(&m_packetQueue);
}

CDVDPlayerAudio::~CDVDPlayerAudio()
{
//  g_dvdPerformanceCounter.DisableAudioQueue();

    // close the stream, and don't wait for the audio to be finished
    CloseStream(true);
    DeleteCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection);
}

bool CDVDPlayerAudio::OpenStream( CDemuxStreamAudio *pDemuxStream )                                 
{
    // should alway's be NULL!!!!, it will probably crash anyway when deleting m_pAudioCodec here.
    if (m_pAudioCodec)
    {
        CLog::Log(LOGFATAL, "CDVDPlayerAudio::OpenStream() m_pAudioCodec != NULL");
        return false;
    }

    AVCodecID codecID = pDemuxStream->codec;

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "Finding audio codec for: %i", codecID);
    //m_pAudioCodec = CDVDFactoryCodec::CreateAudioCodec( pDemuxStream ); 
    m_pAudioCodec = new CDVDAudioCodecFFmpeg; //FIXME BRENT Codec Factory needed!

    if (!m_pAudioCodec->Open(pDemuxStream->codec, pDemuxStream->iChannels, pDemuxStream->iSampleRate))
    {
        m_pAudioCodec->Dispose();
        delete m_pAudioCodec;
        m_pAudioCodec = NULL;
        return false;
    }

    if( !m_pAudioCodec )
    {
        CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "Unsupported audio codec");
        return false;
    }

    m_codec = pDemuxStream->codec;
    m_iSourceChannels = pDemuxStream->iChannels;

    m_messageQueue.Init();

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "Creating audio thread");
    Create();

    return true;
}

void CDVDPlayerAudio::CloseStream(bool bWaitForBuffers)
{
    // wait until buffers are empty
    if (bWaitForBuffers) m_messageQueue.WaitUntilEmpty();

    // send abort message to the audio queue
    m_messageQueue.Abort();

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "waiting for audio thread to exit");

    // shut down the adio_decode thread and wait for it
    StopThread(); // will set this->m_bStop to true
    this->WaitForThreadExit(INFINITE);

    // uninit queue
    m_messageQueue.End();

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "Deleting audio codec");
    if (m_pAudioCodec)
    {
        m_pAudioCodec->Dispose();
        delete m_pAudioCodec;
        m_pAudioCodec = NULL;
    }

    // flush any remaining pts values
    //FlushPTSQueue(); //FIXME BRENT
}

void CDVDPlayerAudio::OnStartup()
{
    CThread::SetName("CDVDPlayerAudio");
    pAudioPacket = NULL;
    m_audioClock = 0;
    audio_pkt_data = NULL;
    audio_pkt_size = 0;

//  g_dvdPerformanceCounter.EnableAudioDecodePerformance(ThreadHandle());
}

void CDVDPlayerAudio::Process()
{
    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "running thread: CDVDPlayerAudio::Process()");

    int result;

    // silence data
    BYTE silence[1024];
    memset(silence, 0, 1024);

    DVDAudioFrame audioframe;

    __int64 iClockDiff=0;
    while (!m_bStop)
    {
        //Don't let anybody mess with our global variables
        EnterCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection);
        result = DecodeFrame(audioframe, m_speed != DVD_PLAYSPEED_NORMAL); // blocks if no audio is available, but leaves critical section before doing so
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection);

        if( result & DECODE_FLAG_ERROR ) 
        {      
            CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "CDVDPlayerAudio::Process - Decode Error. Skipping audio frame");
            continue;
        }

        if( result & DECODE_FLAG_ABORT )
        {
            CLog::Log(LOGDEBUG, "CDVDPlayerAudio::Process - Abort recieved, exiting thread");
            break;
        }

        if( result & DECODE_FLAG_DROP ) //FIXME BRENT
        {
/*          //frame should be dropped. Don't let audio move ahead of the current time thou
            //we need to be able to start playing at any time
            //when playing backwords, we try to keep as small buffers as possible

            // set the time at this delay
            AddPTSQueue(audioframe.pts, m_dvdAudio.GetDelay());
*/
            if (m_speed > 0)
            {
                __int64 timestamp = m_pClock->GetAbsoluteClock() + (audioframe.duration * DVD_PLAYSPEED_NORMAL) / m_speed;
                while( !m_bStop && timestamp > m_pClock->GetAbsoluteClock() ) Sleep(1);
            }
            continue;
        }

        if( audioframe.size > 0 ) 
        {
            // we have succesfully decoded an audio frame, openup the audio device if not already done
            if (!m_bInitializedOutputDevice)
            {
                m_bInitializedOutputDevice = InitializeOutputDevice();
            }

            //Add any packets play
            m_dvdAudio.AddPackets(audioframe.data, audioframe.size);

            // store the delay for this pts value so we can calculate the current playing
            //AddPTSQueue(audioframe.pts, m_dvdAudio.GetDelay() - audioframe.duration);//BRENT
        }

        // if we where asked to resync on this packet, do so here
        if( result & DECODE_FLAG_RESYNC )
        {      
            CLog::Log(LOGDEBUG, "CDVDPlayerAudio::Process - Resync recieved.");
            //while (!m_bStop && (unsigned int)m_dvdAudio.GetDelay() > audioframe.duration ) Sleep(5); //BRENT
            m_pClock->Discontinuity(CLOCK_DISC_NORMAL, audioframe.pts);
        }

#ifdef USEOLDSYNC
        //Clock should be calculated after packets have been added as m_audioClock points to the 
        //time after they have been played

        const __int64 iCurrDiff = (m_audioClock - m_dvdAudio.GetDelay()) - m_pClock->GetClock();
        const __int64 iAvDiff = (iClockDiff + iCurrDiff)/2;

        //Check for discontinuity in the stream, use a moving average to
        //eliminate highfreq fluctuations of large packet sizes
        if( ABS(iAvDiff) > 5000 ) // sync clock if average diff is bigger than 5 msec 
        {
            //Wait untill only the new audio frame wich triggered the discontinuity is left
            //then set disc state
            while (!m_bStop && (unsigned int)m_dvdAudio.GetBytesInBuffer() > audioframe.size ) Sleep(5);

            m_pClock->Discontinuity(CLOCK_DISC_NORMAL, m_audioClock - m_dvdAudio.GetDelay());
            CLog::("CDVDPlayer:: Detected Audio Discontinuity, syncing clock. diff was: %I64d, %I64d, av: %I64d", iClockDiff, iCurrDiff, iAvDiff);
            iClockDiff = 0;
        }
        else
        {      
            //Do gradual adjustments (not working yet)
            //m_pClock->AdjustSpeedToMatch(iClock + iAvDiff);
            iClockDiff = iCurrDiff;
        }
#endif
    }
}

void CDVDPlayerAudio::OnExit()
{
    //g_dvdPerformanceCounter.DisableAudioDecodePerformance();

    // destroy audio device
    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "Closing audio device");
    m_dvdAudio.Destroy();
    m_bInitializedOutputDevice = false;

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "thread end: CDVDPlayerAudio::OnExit()");
}

// decode one audio frame and returns its uncompressed size
int CDVDPlayerAudio::DecodeFrame(DVDAudioFrame &audioframe, bool bDropPacket)
{
    CDVDDemux::DemuxPacket* pPacket = pAudioPacket;
    int n=48000*2*16/8, len;

    //Store amount left at this point, and what last pts was
    unsigned __int64 first_pkt_pts = 0;
    int first_pkt_size = 0; 
    int first_pkt_used = 0;
    int result = 0;

    // make sure the sent frame is clean
    memset(&audioframe, 0, sizeof(DVDAudioFrame));

    if (pPacket)
    {
        first_pkt_pts = pPacket->pts;
        first_pkt_size = pPacket->iSize;
        first_pkt_used = first_pkt_size - audio_pkt_size;
    }

    for (;;)
    {
        /* NOTE: the audio packet can contain several frames */
        while (audio_pkt_size > 0)
        {
            len = m_pAudioCodec->Decode(audio_pkt_data, audio_pkt_size);
            if (len < 0)
            {
                /* if error, we skip the frame */
                audio_pkt_size=0;
                m_pAudioCodec->Reset();
                break;
            }

            // fix for fucked up decoders //FIXME BRENT
            if( len > audio_pkt_size )
            {        
                CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "CDVDPlayerAudio:DecodeFrame - Codec tried to consume more data than available. Potential memory corruption");        
                audio_pkt_size=0;
                m_pAudioCodec->Reset();
                assert(0);
            }

            // get decoded data and the size of it
            audioframe.size = m_pAudioCodec->GetData(&audioframe.data);

            audio_pkt_data += len;
            audio_pkt_size -= len;

            if (audioframe.size <= 0) continue;

            audioframe.pts = m_audioClock;

            // compute duration.
            n = m_pAudioCodec->GetChannels() * m_pAudioCodec->GetBitsPerSample() / 8 * m_pAudioCodec->GetSampleRate();
            if (n > 0)
            {
                // safety check, if channels == 0, n will result in 0, and that will result in a nice devide exception
                audioframe.duration = (unsigned int)(((__int64)audioframe.size * DVD_TIME_BASE) / n);

                // increase audioclock to after the packet
                m_audioClock += audioframe.duration;
            }

            //If we are asked to drop this packet, return a size of zero. then it won't be played
            //we currently still decode the audio.. this is needed since we still need to know it's 
            //duration to make sure clock is updated correctly.
            if( bDropPacket )
            {
                result |= DECODE_FLAG_DROP;
            }
            return result;
        }

        // free the current packet
        if (pPacket)
        {
            CDVDDemuxUtils::FreeDemuxPacket(pPacket); //BRENT FIXME
            pPacket = NULL;
            pAudioPacket = NULL;
        }

        if (m_messageQueue.RecievedAbortRequest()) return DECODE_FLAG_ABORT;

        // read next packet and return -1 on error
        LeaveCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection); //Leave here as this might stall a while

        CDVDMsg* pMsg;
        MsgQueueReturnCode ret = m_messageQueue.Get(&pMsg, INFINITE);

        EnterCriticalSection(&m_critCodecSection);
        if (MSGQ_IS_ERROR(ret) || ret == MSGQ_ABORT) return DECODE_FLAG_ABORT;

        if (pMsg->IsType(CDVDMsg::DEMUXER_PACKET))
        {
            CDVDMsgDemuxerPacket* pMsgDemuxerPacket = (CDVDMsgDemuxerPacket*)pMsg;
            pPacket = pMsgDemuxerPacket->GetPacket();
            pMsgDemuxerPacket->m_pPacket = NULL; // XXX, test
            pAudioPacket = pPacket;
            audio_pkt_data = pPacket->pData;
            audio_pkt_size = pPacket->iSize;
        }
        else
        {
            // other data is not used here, free if
            // msg itself will still be available
            pMsg->Release();
        }

        // if update the audio clock with the pts
        if (pMsg->IsType(CDVDMsg::DEMUXER_PACKET) || pMsg->IsType(CDVDMsg::GENERAL_RESYNC))
        {
            if (pMsg->IsType(CDVDMsg::GENERAL_RESYNC))
            { 
                //player asked us to sync on this package
                CDVDMsgGeneralResync* pMsgGeneralResync = (CDVDMsgGeneralResync*)pMsg;
                result |= DECODE_FLAG_RESYNC;
                m_audioClock = pMsgGeneralResync->GetPts();
            }
            else if (pPacket->pts != DVD_NOPTS_VALUE) // CDVDMsg::DEMUXER_PACKET, pPacket is already set above
            {
                if (first_pkt_size == 0) 
                { 
                    //first package
                    m_audioClock = pPacket->pts;        
                }
                else if (first_pkt_pts > pPacket->pts)
                { 
                    //okey first packet in this continous stream, make sure we use the time here        
                    m_audioClock = pPacket->pts;        
                }
                else if((unsigned __int64)m_audioClock < pPacket->pts || (unsigned __int64)m_audioClock > pPacket->pts)
                {
                    //crap, moved outsided correct pts
                    //Use pts from current packet, untill we find a better value for it.
                    //Should be ok after a couple of frames, as soon as it starts clean on a packet
                    m_audioClock = pPacket->pts;
                }
                else if(first_pkt_size == first_pkt_used)
                {
                    //Nice starting up freshly on the start of a packet, use pts from it
                    m_audioClock = pPacket->pts;
                }
            }
        }
        pMsg->Release();
    }
}

void CDVDPlayerAudio::SetSpeed(int speed)
{ 
    m_speed = speed;

    //if (m_speed == DVD_PLAYSPEED_PAUSE) m_dvdAudio.Pause(); //BRENT FIXME
    //else m_dvdAudio.Resume();
}

bool CDVDPlayerAudio::InitializeOutputDevice()
{
    int iChannels = m_pAudioCodec->GetChannels();
    int iSampleRate = m_pAudioCodec->GetSampleRate();
    int iBitsPerSample = m_pAudioCodec->GetBitsPerSample();
    //bool bPasstrough = m_pAudioCodec->NeedPasstrough(); //BRENT

    if (iChannels == 0 || iSampleRate == 0 || iBitsPerSample == 0)
    {
        CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "Unable to create audio device, (iChannels == 0 || iSampleRate == 0 || iBitsPerSample == 0)");
        return false;
    }

    CLog::Log(LOGNOTICE, "Creating audio device with codec id: %i, channels: %i, sample rate: %i", m_codec, iChannels, iSampleRate);
    if (m_dvdAudio.Create(iChannels, iSampleRate, iBitsPerSample, /*bPasstrough*/0)) // always 16 bit with ffmpeg ? //BRENT Passthrough needed?
    {
        return true;
    }

    CLog::Log(LOGERROR, "Failed Creating audio device with codec id: %i, channels: %i, sample rate: %i", m_codec, iChannels, iSampleRate);
    return false;
}`